# Need to specify WarmType for ES-Domain creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, localstack

Why do i need to specify **"WarmType"** even if it is an optional parameter while creating AWS ES-Domain through **CLI using JSON file** ?
Using this command, rest of the AWS resources are working fine, like DDB,S3 but what's the matter with ES?

```
awslocal es create-elasticsearch-domain --cli-input-json file://filename.json
```

and this is the error i'm getting

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter ClusterConfig.WarmType, value: None, 
type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
```

and this is my **json** file

```
{
            "DomainName":"mydomain",
            "ElasticsearchVersion": "6.8",
            "ElasticsearchClusterConfig": {
              "DedicatedMasterEnabled": true,
              "DedicatedMasterCount": 3,
              "ZoneAwarenessEnabled": false,
              "InstanceCount": 3,
              "InstanceType":"m3.medium.elasticsearch",
              "DedicatedMasterType": "m3.medium.elasticsearch",
              "WarmEnabled":false
            },
            "EBSOptions" : {
                "EBSEnabled" : true,
                "VolumeSize" : 1,
                "VolumeType" : "gp2"
            }
 }
```

Why I'm getting this exception? Even by disabling **"WarmEnabled"** option.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with localstack's validation - I would suggest you open an issue on the github page.

Comment: I've raised an issue on localstack github, but no response.

Comment: I quickly went looking, but found none. You posted a few issues, most of them seem to be usage questions. When posting an issue, always try to be precise about the bug and how somebody can reproduce it

Comment: sure next time ill keep that in mind